# Left join workaround when creating materialized view in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, materialized-views

I have two tables under dataset: `my_dataset` in BigQuery

1. events table

[image]

2. event_attributes table

[image]

Data under these tables is populated via Dataflow job running in GCP.

In `event_attributes` table there are 4 distinct values of attribute_number: [1,2,3,4].

For a given `events_fk` value, there can maximum 4 rows in `event_attributes` table i.e. value of all_count in below query can be max 4.

```
select events_fk, count(*) as all_count from events_attributes group by events_fk order by all_count limit 1
```

Now, I want to **create a materialized view, which has** *count of all events, count of completed events (from events table) **grouped by** time, app, completed, attribute_value(from event_attributes table)*. For this, I'm trying to use below query

```
create materialized view my_dataset.test_mv as (
  select 
  extract(DATE FROM timestamp_seconds(epoch_seconds_utc)) as date,
  extract(HOUR FROM timestamp_seconds(epoch_seconds_utc)) as hour,
  app,
  completed,
  attribute_value,
  count(*) as all_count,
  sum(cast(completed as tinyint)) as completed_count
  from `my_dataset.events` c
  left join unnest(
    (
      select array_agg( struct(id, events_fk, attribute_number, attribute_value) ) as eattr
      from `my_dataset.event_attributes`
    )
  ) a
  on c.id = a.events_fk
  group by date, hour, app, completed, attribute_value
)
```

Since, left join is not supported in creating materialized view as of now, I was trying to use unnest() and provide an array arguments inside that as a work around.
But, bigquery complains about this with below error

[image]

I'm guessing it's because of the subquery that I'm using under unnest().

**Reason for trying to create materialized view:** I want to use the created materialized view for constructing different reports.

My requirements are-

1. Have to combine the data in two different table and use resulting table to create materialized view.
2. Have all rows of events table considered for the final materialized view calculation(which can't be done if I use inner join).

I've also thought of having combined data of these two tables in the dataflow stage itself. But that will be a long route as of now. Since, I will have to think about the changes in dataflow job.

**Question:** Need help with the create materialized view query. If query is not possible what should be the best course of action in such situation?
Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!!

**Edit:** Sample data can be constructed via below queries

```
create table my_dataset.events (
  id INTEGER,
  epoch_seconds_utc INTEGER,
  app STRING,
  engaged BOOLEAN,
  completed BOOLEAN
);

create table my_dataset.event_attributes (
  id INTEGER,
  events_fk INTEGER,
  attribute_number STRING,
  attribute_value STRING
)


-- POPULATE EVENTS DATA
insert into `my_dataset.events` values (435515, 1660807131, 'airtel', FALSE, FALSE);
insert into `my_dataset.events` values (435517, 1660807514, 'vodafone', FALSE, FALSE);
insert into `my_dataset.events` values (285111, 1607927586, 'telstra', FALSE, FALSE);
insert into `my_dataset.events` values (435051, 1649137598, 'healthways', FALSE, FALSE);
insert into `my_dataset.events` values (435017, 1649068151, 'tangoe', FALSE, FALSE);
insert into `my_dataset.events` values (435519, 1660821334, 'airtel', FALSE, FALSE);
insert into `my_dataset.events` values (703, 1589840471,    'vodafone', FALSE, FALSE);
insert into `my_dataset.events` values (1619, 1591014513, 'telstra', FALSE, FALSE);
insert into `my_dataset.events` values (783, 1589840537, 'tangoe', FALSE, FALSE);
insert into `my_dataset.events` values (20245, 1596825490, 'healthways', FALSE, FALSE);


-- POPULATE EVENT ATTRIBUTES DATA
insert into `my_dataset.event_attributes` values (6341, 435017, '1',    'In Progress');
insert into `my_dataset.event_attributes` values (6381, 435051, '1',    'In Progress');
insert into `my_dataset.event_attributes` values (5429, 285111, '1',    '9191919191');
insert into `my_dataset.event_attributes` values (5431, 285111, '2',    'Direct Connection');
insert into `my_dataset.event_attributes` values (5433, 285111, '3',    'English');
insert into `my_dataset.event_attributes` values (5435, 285111, '4',    'Covid');
insert into `my_dataset.event_attributes` values (7161, 435517, '3',    'English');
insert into `my_dataset.event_attributes` values (7159, 435517, '2',    'Some value');
insert into `my_dataset.event_attributes` values (7151, 435515, '2', 'Some value');
insert into `my_dataset.event_attributes` values (7163, 435517, '4',    'Default');
insert into `my_dataset.event_attributes` values (7157, 435517, '1',    '50000');
insert into `my_dataset.event_attributes` values (7149, 435515, '1',    '50000');
insert into `my_dataset.event_attributes` values (7153, 435515, '3',    'English');
insert into `my_dataset.event_attributes` values (7155, 435515, '4',    'Default');
```

In this if you perform an inner join using query like

```
select e.id, ea.attribute_number, ea.attribute_value
```

from my_dataset.events e left join my_dataset.event_attributes ea
on e.id=ea.events_fk

I get around 14 rows, and if I use left join in above query, I get around 19 rows because there are records in events table which don't have corresponding entry in event_attributes.

**Desired output:** want to get all rows of events table considered to create materialized view.

Let me know if any information is needed from my end.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired output for us to reproduce your scenario.

Comment: @AnjelaB have attached the sample data with desired output

Comment: It would help me if you give raw data of each table (`events` and `event_attributes`) so that i may come up with different approach if needed.

Comment: @AnjelaB I'll provide the queries to have short sample data, will that work?

Comment: Yes if you can.

Comment: @AnjelaB updated question with queries to populate sample data. Please try once and let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247567/discussion-between-akki-and-anjela-b).

Answer (score 1):

As Consulted with a Googler:

Material view is good when writing to source is not as much as reading from the sources and having a pre-processed data will save time or cost, or when incremental refresh would benefit. [1]

With left join not supported, you may consider following:

- Denormalizing tables into one table: combining two source tables into one would get rid of the need to use join statements.
- Using scheduled query to create a new table using the query used for the materialized view: while this option doesn’t run the query every time data is read from the source, this could result in data staleness.
- Recreating table that runs query used for the materialized view inside the Dataflow job: while this would not lead to data staleness, this does not support incremental refresh and may have performance difference.

For comparison of other resource types, refer to [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro#use_cases

[2] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro#comparison

Comment: Thanks for all the help!! For now, I've created a temporary table on top of source tables. I've created materialized view using this temporary table. Since, data is coming to source tables via dataflow job, my only problem remains to transfer data from source table to temporary table. For this I've created a scheduled query, which retrieves the last 15 minutes data from source table and inserts into temporary table. I'm yet to verify this, will update after that.